# Configure Sunspot Solr search with scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, solr, sunspot, sunspot-solr

**Controller**

```
class GearsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_gear, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def primary
    @gears = Gear.search do
      with(:Lab, 'Primary')
      order_by(:RU, :desc)
    end
  end
```

**Model**

```
class Gear < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :Nic1mac, :Nic2mac, :Nic3mac, :IBmac, :SN, :allow_blank => true
  attr_readonly :Devtype, :Nic1mac, :Nic2mac, :Nic3mac, :IBmac, :SN

  scope :Mini, -> { where(lab: 'Mini') }
  scope :Primary, -> { where(lab: 'Primary') }
  scope :Support, -> { where(lab: 'Support') }
  scope :M5, -> { where(lab: 'M5') }
  scope :P5, -> { where(lab: 'P5') }

  searchable do
    integer :RU
    text :Devname
    text :Devtype
    string :Lab
    text :Swportib
    text :Swport1
    text :Swport2
    text :Swport3
    text :IBip
    text :Nic1
    text :Nic2
    text :Nic3
    text :Nic1mac
    text :Nic2mac
    text :Nic3mac
    text :IBmac
    text :Psu1
    text :Psu2
    text :SN
 end
end
```

**View**

```
<% provide(:title, "SP4 Primary") %>
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>SP4 Primary</h1>

<%= form_tag gears_path, :method => :get do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<head>
<style>
table, th, td { border: 1px solid black;}
th, td { padding: 15px;}
</style>
</head>

<table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
      <th>RU</th>
      <th>Dev Name</th>
      <th>Dev Type</th>
      <th>Lab</th>
      <th>SW PortIB</th>
      <th>SW Port1</th>
      <th>SW Port2</th>
      <th>SW Port3</th>
      <th>IB IP</th>
      <th>NIC1</th>
      <th>NIC2</th>
      <th>NIC3</th>
      <th>NIC1 Mac</th>
      <th>NIC2 Mac</th>
      <th>NIC3 Mac</th>
      <th>IB Mac</th>
      <th>PSU1</th>
      <th>PSU2</th>
      <th>SN</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>
    <% @gears.each do |gear| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= gear.RU %></td>
        <td><%= gear.Devname %></td>
        <td><%= gear.Devtype %></td>
        <td><%= gear.Lab %></td>
        <td><%= gear.Swportib %></td>
        <td><%= gear.Swport1 %></td>
        <td><%= gear.Swport2 %></td>
        <td><%= gear.Swport3 %></td>
        <td><%= gear.IBip %></td>
        <td><%= gear.Nic1 %></td>
        <td><%= gear.Nic2 %></td>
        <td><%= gear.Nic3 %></td>
        <td><%= gear.Nic1mac %></td>
        <td><%= gear.Nic2mac %></td>
        <td><%= gear.Nic3mac %></td>
        <td><%= gear.IBmac %></td>
        <td><%= gear.Psu1 %></td>
        <td><%= gear.Psu2 %></td>
        <td><%= gear.SN %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', gear %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_gear_path(gear) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', gear, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>
```

Above is my Controller and Model code. I am trying to set up the search so it only searches through records within the scope specified. Currently it will return all results and does not pay attention to the scope. I believe I am close to making it work but just don't have the right syntax. Then again I may be wrong, thus any help suggestions or different ways of doing this are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was adding `without` in my gears_controller.rb file.

***gears_controller.rb***

```
 def rack1
    @gears = Gear.where("Lab like ? OR Lab like ? OR Lab like ?", "%Primary%", "%Mini%", "%Support%")
    @search = Gear.search do
      fulltext params[:search]
      without(:Lab, "P5")
      without(:Lab, "M5")
      order_by(:RU, :desc)
  end
    @gears = @search.results
  end
```

Adding the without fields allowed me to only search through the records with the specific Lab values that were specified in my `@gears` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a code like this in your search method

```
with(:lab, 'Support')
```

and in your model add this

```
string :lab
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion @rocki but still no luck. I continue to receive all results and not just the ones within the scope.

Comment: you must kill your server and run rake sunspot:solr:reindex

Comment: @aealvarez3 please accept the answer if it has worked for you

Comment: i have killed my server and ran rake sunspot:solr:reindex multiple times and still no luck.

Comment: Have you changed your lab to string in your model instead of using text

Comment: yes in my model i changed "text :Lab" to "string :Lab" under my "searchable do".